# Android intent.putExtra java.lang.illegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android

I have a class called `AdViewed` that implements `Parcelable`.

Here is the code:

```
public class AdViewed implements Parcelable {

    protected long timeStamp;
    protected String country, city, lat, lng, ad_id, poster_id, user_id, latLng;

    public void hydrate(HashMap<String, ?> map){
        Method[] methodes = this.getClass().getMethods();
        Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Object key = it.next();
            Object value = map.get(key);
            String valueS = value.toString();

            String method = "set" + key.toString();

            for(Method methode : methodes){
                if(methode.getName().equals(method)){
                    try{
                        methode.invoke(AdViewed.this,  valueS);
                    }
                    catch(InvocationTargetException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(IllegalAccessException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public AdViewed(long timeStamp1, String country1, String city1, String lat1, String lng1, String ad_id1, String poster_id1,
                    String user_id1, String latLng1){
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp1;
        this.country = country1;
        this.city = city1;
        this.lat = lat1;
        this.lng = lng1;
        this.ad_id = ad_id1;
        this.poster_id = poster_id1;
        this.user_id = user_id1;
        this.latLng = latLng1;
    }

    public AdViewed(){
        this.timeStamp = 0 ;
        this.country = "";
        this.city = "";
        this.lat = "";
        this.lng = "";
        this.ad_id = "";
        this.poster_id = "";
        this.user_id = "";
        this.latLng = "";
    }

    public AdViewed(HashMap<String, ?> map){
        this.timeStamp = 0;
        this.country = "";
        this.city = "";
        this.lat = "";
        this.lng = "";
        this.ad_id = "";
        this.poster_id = "";
        this.user_id = "";
        this.latLng = "";

        if(!map.isEmpty()){
            this.hydrate(map);
            //erreurs = new ArrayList();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents(){
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){
        dest.writeLong(timeStamp);
        dest.writeString(country);
        dest.writeString(city);
        dest.writeString(lat);
        dest.writeString(lng);
        dest.writeString(ad_id);
        dest.writeString(poster_id);
        dest.writeString(user_id);
        dest.writeString(latLng);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<AdViewed> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<AdViewed>(){
        @Override
        public AdViewed createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new AdViewed(source);
        }

        @Override
        public AdViewed[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AdViewed[size];
        }

    };

    public AdViewed(Parcel in){
        timeStamp = in.readLong();
        country = in.readString();
        city = in.readString();
        lat = in.readString();
        lng = in.readString();
        ad_id = in.readString();
        poster_id = in.readString();
        user_id = in.readString();
        latLng = in.readString();
    }

    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(long timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getAd_id() {
        return ad_id;
    }

    public void setAd_id(String ad_id) {
        this.ad_id = ad_id;
    }

    public String getPoster_id() {
        return poster_id;
    }

    public void setPoster_id(String poster_id) {
        this.poster_id = poster_id;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getLatLng() {
        return latLng;
    }

    public void setLatLng(String latLng) {
        this.latLng = latLng;
    }
}
```

And I have another class `AdInDeal` that derives from AdViewed. Here is its code:

```
public class AdInDeal extends AdViewed {

    protected String qte, costPerUnit, totalCost, imgPath;
    protected boolean onCommand, onAcheteur, onVendeur;
    protected int statutDeal;

public AdInDeal(AdInDeal adInDeal){

    myInflation(adInDeal);
}

    public void myInflation(AdInDeal adInDeal1){
        this.setUser_id(adInDeal1.user_id);
        this.setCostPerUnit(adInDeal1.getCostPerUnit());
        this.setImgPath(adInDeal1.getImgPath());
        this.setOnAcheteur(adInDeal1.isOnAcheteur());
        this.setOnCommand(adInDeal1.isOnCommand());
        this.setOnVendeur(adInDeal1.isOnVendeur());
        this.setQte(adInDeal1.getQte());
        this.setStatutDeal(adInDeal1.getStatutDeal());
        this.setTotalCost(adInDeal1.getTotalCost());
        this.setAd_id(adInDeal1.getAd_id());
        this.setCity(adInDeal1.getCity());
        this.setCountry(adInDeal1.getCountry());
        this.setLat(adInDeal1.getLat());
        this.setLng(adInDeal1.getLng());
        this.setLatLng(adInDeal1.getLatLng());
        this.setPoster_id(adInDeal1.getPoster_id());
        this.setTimeStamp(adInDeal1.getTimeStamp());
    }

    public AdInDeal(long timeStamp1, String country1, String city1, String lat1, String lng1, String ad_id1, String poster_id1,
                    String user_id1, String latLng1, String qte1, String costPerUnit1, String totalCost1){

        super(timeStamp1, country1, city1, lat1, lng1, ad_id1, poster_id1,
                user_id1, latLng1);

        this.qte = qte1;
        this.costPerUnit = costPerUnit1;
        this.totalCost = totalCost1;
        this.imgPath = "";
        this.onCommand = false;
        this.onAcheteur = false;
        this.onVendeur = false;
        this.statutDeal = 0;
    }

    public AdInDeal(long timeStamp1, String country1, String city1, String lat1, String lng1, String ad_id1, String poster_id1,
                    String user_id1, String latLng1, String qte1, String costPerUnit1, String totalCost1, String imgPath1){

        super(timeStamp1, country1, city1, lat1, lng1, ad_id1, poster_id1,
                user_id1, latLng1);

        this.qte = qte1;
        this.costPerUnit = costPerUnit1;
        this.totalCost = totalCost1;
        this.imgPath = imgPath1;
        this.onCommand = false;
        this.onAcheteur = false;
        this.onVendeur = false;
        this.statutDeal = 0;
    }


    public AdInDeal(long timeStamp1, String country1, String city1, String lat1, String lng1, String ad_id1, String poster_id1,
                    String user_id1, String latLng1, String qte1, String costPerUnit1, String totalCost1,
                    String imgPath1, boolean onCommand1, boolean onAcheteur1, boolean onVendeur1, int statutDeal1){

        super(timeStamp1, country1, city1, lat1, lng1, ad_id1, poster_id1,
                user_id1, latLng1);

        this.qte = qte1;
        this.costPerUnit = costPerUnit1;
        this.totalCost = totalCost1;
        this.imgPath = imgPath1;
        this.onCommand = onCommand1;
        this.onAcheteur = onAcheteur1;
        this.onVendeur = onVendeur1;
        this.statutDeal = statutDeal1;
    }
    public AdInDeal(){
        super();
        this.qte = "";
        this.costPerUnit = "";
        this.totalCost = "";
        this.imgPath = "";
        this.onCommand = false;
        this.onAcheteur = false;
        this.onVendeur = false;
        this.statutDeal = 0;
    }

    public AdInDeal(HashMap<String, ?> map){
        super(map);
        this.qte = "";
        this.costPerUnit = "";
        this.totalCost = "";
        this.imgPath = "";
        this.onCommand = false;
        this.onAcheteur = false;
        this.onVendeur = false;
        this.statutDeal = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);

        dest.writeString(qte);
        dest.writeString(costPerUnit);
        dest.writeString(totalCost);
        dest.writeString(imgPath);
        dest.writeInt(statutDeal);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (onCommand ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeByte((byte) (onAcheteur ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeByte((byte) (onVendeur ? 1 : 0));
    }

    public AdInDeal(Parcel in){
        super(in);

        qte = in.readString();
        costPerUnit = in.readString();
        totalCost = in.readString();
        imgPath = in.readString();
        statutDeal = in.readInt();
        onCommand = in.readByte() != 0;
        onAcheteur = in.readByte() != 0;
        onVendeur = in.readByte() != 0;

    }

    public String getQte() {
        return qte;
    }

    public void setQte(String qte) {
        this.qte = qte;
    }

    public String getCostPerUnit() {
        return costPerUnit;
    }

    public void setCostPerUnit(String costPerUnit) {
        this.costPerUnit = costPerUnit;
    }

    public String getTotalCost() {
        return totalCost;
    }

    public void setTotalCost(String totalCost) {
        this.totalCost = totalCost;
    }

    public String getImgPath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    public void setImgPath(String imgPath) {
        this.imgPath = imgPath;
    }

    public boolean isOnCommand() {
        return onCommand;
    }

    public void setOnCommand(boolean onCommand) {
        this.onCommand = onCommand;
    }

    public boolean isOnVendeur() {
        return onVendeur;
    }

    public void setOnVendeur(boolean onVendeur) {
        this.onVendeur = onVendeur;
    }

    public boolean isOnAcheteur() {
        return onAcheteur;
    }

    public void setOnAcheteur(boolean onAcheteur) {
        this.onAcheteur = onAcheteur;
    }

    public int getStatutDeal() {
        return statutDeal;
    }

    public void setStatutDeal(int statutDeal) {
        this.statutDeal = statutDeal;
    }
}
```

I have also an `Activity`, let's call it `ActivityA`. `ActivityA` use an `Intent` to go to another activity (which we will call `ActivityB`).

Here is the code for `ActivityA`:

```
AdInDeal adInDeal = new AdInDeal(111111111, "Canada", "Torronto", "43.620595", "-79.376129", "id1",  "poster_id1" , "user_id1", "43.620595, -79.376129", "10", "100", "1000", "imgPath1")

Intent intent = new Intent(activityA.this, activityB.class);
intent.putExtra("text1", "A small text");
intent.putExtra("text2", adInDeal);//If I delete this line I have no problem
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the code for `ActivityB`:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();

if(mIntent != null){
  String mText = mIntent.getStringExtra("text1");
  AdInDeal mAdInDeal = mIntent.getParcelableExtra("text2");
  Toast.makeText(this, mAdInDeal.getQte(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When I compile and run this code, I get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Depending on the debugger, it comes from the line:

```
AdInDeal mAdInDeal = mIntent.getParcelableExtra("text2");
```

In `ActivityB`.

But I found out that the problem is actually in `ActivityA` at the line:

```
intent.putExtra("text2", adInDeal);
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Please don't use *code snippets* for code which is not HTML, CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Put the full stracktrace here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That is a lot of code you have posted! In the future, please try and reduce the problem to an [MCVE] . Then the example will be useful for future readers as well.